# Can I use rsync to synchronise files in all directions?

Tags: rsync

I am setting up a webserver cluster and there is the facility for certain files to be uploaded.

This can happen on any of the web nodes and I am trying to work out the best way to distribute the files from each webserver to all of the rest of them.

Is this something that can be achieved with rsync? All of the examples I have seen talk about local -> remote(s), but in this case new files could appear on any node.

If not I will write my own process, but I thought I'd check before re-inventing the wheel!

Comment: NFS, please....

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Please! :)

Look into cluster filesystems like Ceph or GlusterFS. These will take care of synchronization for you.

Another frequently-used option is to have a storage server that exports a filesystem via NFS to the web tier. Then the webservers are able to read and write data to the same volume concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to run rsync sessions between every node, not going to scale well.  Look at a clustered filesystem or use a central file store that's mounted to the various web nodes.

Answer (score 0):

A clustered/distributed file system may be overkill.

Have a look at [csync2](http://oss.linbit.com/csync2/) (to perform the actual syncs) and [lsyncd](https://code.google.com/p/lsyncd/) (daemon that runs commands when a file system change occurs.

The sync will be asynchronous, but that usually good for the situation you describe